# Creating an optimized pattern using Text::Balanced to format with Text::Markdown

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module

I can run the following on a csv file in order to get the delimited text from the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced q/extract_delimited/;

my $filecontents = do { local $/; <> };

while (my $item = extract_delimited($filecontents, '"')) {
    print "Item: $item\n";
}
```

but the results always include the quotes which is what I do not want so I tried the following to completely isolate the multi line record

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced qw/gen_delimited_pat/;

my $filecontents = do { local $/; <> };
$patstring = gen_delimited_patq(\G(?:[^"]|""|""")* ]))

while (my $item = extract_delimited($filecontents, '"')) {
    print "Item: $item\n";
}
```

since I know this regex

```
\G(?:[^"]|""|""")*
```

finds the complete multi line record that I would like to then process with Text::Markdown however I get errors that

- Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at line 10.
- Global symbol "$patstring" requires explicit package name at line 10.
- Search pattern not terminated at line 10.

I am trying to only get the delimited text for record that looks something like this excluding the beginning and ending quote I hope this makes sense:

"description"
"Star-Lite 2-Person w/Fly Aluminum, Rust

Specifications:

- Packed size: 13"" X 5""
- 1 Door
- Interior Area: 41.25 sq. ft.
- Peak Height: 44""
- Floor Material: 190T polyester, 2000mm P.U. coated
- Mesh: No-see-um
- Number of poles: 2 shock corded aluminum 8.5 mm.
- Pole sections: 12"" lengths.
- Rainfly Included.
- 90"" X 66"" X 44"""

Excluding the first row I only want

Star-Lite 2-Person w/Fly Aluminum, Rust

Specifications:

- Packed size: 13"" X 5""
- 1 Door
- Interior Area: 41.25 sq. ft.
- Peak Height: 44""
- Floor Material: 190T polyester, 2000mm P.U. coated
- Mesh: No-see-um
- Number of poles: 2 shock corded aluminum 8.5 mm.
- Pole sections: 12"" lengths.
- Rainfly Included.
- 90"" X 66"" X 44""

What do I need to do to fix my pattern for this module?

EDIT: Pasted the wrong script that worked

Comment: Can you give some sample input and what you're expecting to get out?

Answer (score 1):

A bit inelegant, but this will do what I think you want to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Balanced qw/extract_delimited extract_multiple/;

my $filecontents = do { local $/; <> };

#replace newlines with pipes
$filecontents=~s/\n/\|/g;
$filecontents=~s/""/inches/g;
#grab all your delimited substrings into an array
my @extracted = extract_multiple($filecontents,
                            [ sub {extract_delimited ($_[0],q{"})}],
                            undef, 1);

foreach my $fragment(@extracted){
    #remove "
    $fragment=~s/"//g;
    $fragment=~s/inches/""/g;
    $fragment=~s/\|/\n/g;
    print "$fragment\n";  
}
```

Comment: this gives errors - Global symbol "$filecontents" requires explicit package name at line 11.
- Global symbol "$filecontents" requires explicit package name at line 13.
- Execution of C:\wamp\bin\Perl\playground\trial5.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: works for me... turn off strict if it's making that moan, but it shouldn't be: **my** $filecontents = do { local $/; <> };

Comment: Since this file has 5000+ records in the description field that are variable in length perl keeps choking on trying to process this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Global symbol "$patstring" requires explicit package name at line 10.
```

You have [strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) on and forgot to declare the `$patstring` variable.

```
Use of ?PATTERN? without explicit operator is deprecated at line 10
```

[gen_delimited_pat](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aBalanced#gen_delimited_pat) takes a string.  You've passed it... well, you've passed it a syntax error.  I guess it's supposed to be a regex?  Perl has, in desperation, tried to parse it as a [?PATTERN?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) using the single question mark and then given up.

Neither example you give should ever have worked.  Both contain the same errors above.  There is no Text::Balanced function called `gen_delimited_patq` (it is `gen_delimited_pat`), neither exports the correct functions from Text::Balanced and `$patstring` is never used.

Comment: the first example was pasted wrong it was essentially what I was trying to do with the second one.